# in Euclidean space defined by multivariate normal distribution, what fraction of points falls within n-ball (centered at origin) tangent to point p?

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

In a Euclidean space defined by the [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), what fraction of *all* points falls within or are tangent to (as opposed to falling outside of) the n-sphere whose center is at the origin and which is tangent to the point *p* represented by Cartesian coordinates:

vector(θ) =(θ<sub>1</sub>, θ<sub>2</sub>, θ<sub>3</sub>, θ<sub>4</sub> θ<sub>5</sub>, ... θ<sub>n</sub>)

representing sigmas in the multivariate normal distribution in n dimensions?

This is a post-doctoral question and I could not find it in the literature.  I tried searches for the terms you see in the subject line.

p.s. in terms of [the picture in the link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/MultivariateNormal.png), the question is: "what fraction of all the dots are in the green circle?" (where in this case the green circle is defined by an arbitrary point on its circumference.)

In terms of [R-programming-language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) code I would like to give a vector and get back a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Also asked in MO.  But here is a better place to put it.    To make this better, define what your distribution is.  When you say "$(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$ represent the sigmas in the normal distribution" I guess you mean: the Cartesian components $X_k$ are independent, mean zero, and variance $\theta_k^2$.  Is that right?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question.  The linked image is an ellipse rather than a circle, since the covariance matrix is not an identity matrix. Does tangent to a point mean the point is in the surface of the sphere/ellipsoid? Is the mean of the distribution at the origin? Is the probability requested going to be related to $\chi^2_n$ or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Yes  GEdgar it is as you write.

Can you give me [R (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) code that gives the fraction for such a set of independent, mean zero, variance θ^2 cartesian components?

Comment: Henry, yes, tangent to a point means the point is in the surface of the n-ball (n-sphere).  The mean of the distribution is at the origin. I don't know the formula I'm asking for or whether or not it's related to χ2. Ideally I would appreciate some [R (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) code that answers the question.

Comment: Asking for R code is off-topic in this group.

Comment: GEdgar, may I ask for an explicit formula?